# node_modules/@types/lodash/common/lang.d.ts: - error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library?

Tags: typescript

I'm a C# developer, trying to transition to TypeScript and Angular.
I've defined a declaration file in my solution under

> Activity2.01/types/HeatMapTypes.d.ts

```
declare module "HeatMapTypes" {
    export interface Pitcher {
        batterHotZones: Array<Array<number>>; 
        pitcherHotZones: Array<Array<number>>;
        coordinateMap?: Array<Array<number>>;
    }
}
```

And I have a regular TypeScript file under

> Activity2.01/heat_map_data.ts

```
/// <reference  path = "./types/HeatMapTypes.d.ts" />
import hmt = require("HeatMapTypes");
import _ = require("lodash");

export let data: hmt.Pitcher;
data =  
{
    batterHotZones : [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
    pitcherHotZones: [[1, 2, 3], [8, 9, 10], [4, 8, 5]],
}

export const findMatch = function (batterHotZoneLocal: Array <Array<number>>, 
    pitcherHotZoneLocal: Array<Array<number>>) : Array<Array<number>> 
{
    let result: Array<Array<number>> = _.intersectionWith(batterHotZoneLocal, 
        pitcherHotZoneLocal, _.isEqual);
    return result;
}

data.coordinateMap = findMatch(data.batterHotZones, data.pitcherHotZones);
console.log(data.coordinateMap);
```

I get no redline errors in VS Code, but when I run the commond

> tsc heat_map_data.ts

in node command prompt, I'm getting 6 different errors in my code.

[image]

As the error suggest, I tried adding ES2015 in my 'tsconfig.json' file, "lib": ["ES2015", "DOM"] is the current configuration. Also, I checked and found that the "not-found" methods are actually available in 'lang.d.ts' file. In addition, I've tried running a few commands in node cmd, that were mentioned in other posts.
Can someone tell me what may be the origin of these errors and how can these be resolved. Also, how to navigate the errors in typescript for effective resolution? The messages seem to be too vague and unrelated to actual errors.
Thank you.

Comment: Don't use triple slash references or ambient modules wrappers for code like that. Just export and import: `export interface Pitcher {}` `import {Pitcher} from './types/HeatMapTypes';`